# How to create a package of nodes and media?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

In Umbraco 6.1.6, I get an exception while trying to install a package that includes one of my root content nodes. This is probably due to not including the media in the package.

However, I do not wish to copy my entire media folder. 
In my media section there is a specific media folder for that exact node that I'd like to include.

How can I create a package with all my necessary data that can be installed fully in another Umbraco instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can't choose a few items in the packaging wizard.
Try other options like

- Courrier (http://umbraco.com/products/more-add-ons/courier-2.aspx)
- creating your own export/import  (serialize content you want)
- database scripts (at your own risk)
- check the umbraco forum (http://our.umbraco.org/forum) to see if someone else has tried it